# Login to Office 365 programmatically

Tags: c#, authentication, office365, adfs

I would like to login programmatically to office 365.

I create an RSTR , put it in wresult paramter , add these parameters :

```
&wa=wsignin1.0&MEST=0&rver=6.1.6206.0&LoginOptions=2&lc=1033&rpsnv=2&wp=MBI&cbcxt=mai&wlidp=1&guest=1&vv=910&mkt=EN-US&bk=1343219930&ct=1343219880
```

Then submit to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf/

My questions are :

Are the parameters I put in the request correct ?
Are there some special claims I need to put in the RSTR ?

I'm really struggling with this.

Any help please ?

Comment: Why are you trying to sign in programmatically? I ask because most things can be done programmatically either through PowerShell or different APIs. Perhaps you wouldn't need to sign in programmatically?

Comment: Hi Philippe, it's a custom solution I use , I create a custom STS ( ADFS ) in order to log in to 0365. Actually I found the solution , it's a matter of claims and a correct configuration of ADFS. Sorry for late reply. We use ADFS in order to log into O365.

Comment: What are you trying to sign into from?  Is it from an AD joined machine or external from your network?